# Google Sheets - query and sum data from two spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have 2 interesting columns (`Serial Number`, `Value`) in 2 separate sheets. In a third sheet (`sheet3`) I have a `query` that groups the values by serial number (and sums the values accordingly) - **but only from `sheet1`**. The query also applies a lambda function on the sum process (just adds 1 if column C says "yes").

I just added the numbers for `sheet2`, and am trying to update the query in `sheet3` to include the numbers from `sheet2`, but it won't work. I tried simply changing the first `query` param from `Sheet1!A2:A` to `Sheet1!A2:A;Sheet2!A2:A`, but that results in an error.

So my question is - how do add the data from `sheet2` to the `query` in `sheet3` (the lambda/condition must still work only for the data from `sheet1`, it doesn't apply to `sheet2`)?

Sample spreadsheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QoTrNmCecX1W3F2wNnxeA77yIE5wHPm7tEYlbSumWcY/edit?usp=sharing

Current `query` is:

`=query({Sheet1!A2:A, MAP(Sheet1!B2:B,Sheet1!C2:C, LAMBDA(value,condition, IF(condition="yes", value+1, value)))}, "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 'Serial Number', sum(Col2) 'Value'")`

Sheet1:

[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2:

[image: Sheet2]

Sheet3:

[image: Sheet3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can try:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   QUERY({Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!B2:B+(Sheet1!C2:C="yes");
          Sheet2!A2:B},
     "select Col1, sum(Col2)
      where Col1<>''
      group by Col1
      label Col1 'Serial Number', sum(Col2) 'Value'"))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the MAP+LAMBDA because in the original file it's more complicated than just "yes", I just added a simple condition here for the sample sheet. Is there a way to do this leaving MAP+LAMBDA as is?

Comment: you can simply replace `Sheet1!B2:B+(Sheet1!C2:C="yes")` with your MAP formula. But I advice against using lambda helper functions for things that can be easily accomplished without them because if they are processing too many values they may run into calculation limit.